# java invocation builder how to get the response as a string for logging?

Tags: java, json, rest

We are getting back json from a rest API which we try to marshal into an object. However, because this does not always work, we want to also log every raw response body as a string (or possibly only if ther is a marshalling exception). E.g:

```
Response response = invocationBuilder.get();
int statusCode = response.getStatus();
if (statusCode != 200 && statusCode !=201 && stausCode != 404) {
    logger.error("Got a strange response: " + response.????
}

// this may fail with exceptions...
MyResponseDO myResponse = response.readEntity(MyResponseDO.class);

return myResponse;
```

Any suggestions?  I cant see anything useful on the Response class (there is no getBody() or similar).

Answer (score 0):

Since JSON is just a string, it can be mapped to the string type. You can get raw response using:

```
response.readEntity(String.class);
```

Note: `readEntity` closes the data stream, that means you can not to call `readEntity` again. From [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#readEntity-java.lang.Class-):

> A message instance returned from this method will be cached for subsequent retrievals via getEntity(). Unless the supplied entity type is an input stream, this method automatically **closes** the an unconsumed original response entity data stream if open.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, but get a stream reset error message when I then try to parse the response into my object.

Comment: @JohnLittle Did you try to call `readEntity` twice? In this case it won't work.. Could you please add full error message

Comment: Yes, I tried to read it as a string so as to log it, then I read it as my response object to put it into a usable object, which fails with the stream reset error.  I guess the solution is to do something like read the response as a string, then use the string to convert it into an object.  I am surprised there are no examples of this, as its the only way to debug what comes back from the api.